# Printing string input enclosed with a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning for loops right now and I did a basic program that takes string inputs and an integer input. The program will print the string and will split the strings based on the integer input. How do I make it something like this?

```
-------
|jhdsj|
|alhds|
|hja21|
|dasj |
-------
```

Here's what I have done so far

```
string = input("String = ")
length = int(input("Length = ")

for in range (0, len(string), length):
    print("|", string[i:i+length],"|")
```

Comment: Please make clear what your expected input and output are. Right now it's not clear what's wrong with your current implementation.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code... please fix them. Could you provide desired input and output?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness What do you mean syntax error, my code perfectly works fine

Comment: Can you provide an example of what goes into the program(your inputs). Also you’re missing something very important in the declaration of your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
string = input("String = ")
length = int(input("Length = "))

string = string + ' ' * (length - (len(string) % length)) #add padding if required
print('-'*(length+2))
for i in range (0, len(string), length):
    print('|' + string[i:i+length] + '|')
print('-'*(length+2))
```

Required formatting might require padding of extra whitespaces, which is done by

```
string = string + ' ' * (length - (len(string) % length))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I guess correctly what you want to do you need to use `ljust`

```py
string = input("String = ")
length = int(input("Length = "))

print('-'*(length+2))
for i in range (0, len(string), length):
    print("|{}|".format(string[i:i+length].ljust(length)))
print('-'*(length+2))
```

Output:

```py
String = thisisanexample
Length = 4
------
|this|
|isan|
|exam|
|ple |
------
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string = input("String = ")
length = int(input("Length = "))

if (len(string)%length) > 0:
    string = string + len(string)%length * ' '

for i in range (0, len(string)//length):
    print("|", string[i*length:i*length+length],"|")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is (in principle) correct, I only fixed syntax errors:

```
string = input("String = ")
length = int(input("Length = "))          # added parenthesis

for i in range(0, len(string), length):   # added variable i
    print("|", string[i:i+length],"|")
```

Output (with input):

> ```
> String = 123456789
> Length = 4
> | 1234 |
> | 5678 |
> | 9 |
> ```

---

Note:

If you want symbols `|` to be aligned, you may use these 3 lines instead of your last line (i.e. instead of your `print("|", string[i:i+length],"|")` command):

```
    part = string[i:i+length]
    part += (length - len(part)) * " "         # append appropriate number of spaces
    print("|", part,"|")
```

Output (with input):

> ```
> String = 123456789
> Length = 4
> | 1234 |
> | 5678 |
> | 9    |
> ```